# Can a PCI bus master access a device mapped in cpu memory space

Tags: memory, bus, pci

If a PCI bus master can access memory space just as cpu can, can it put an address on the memory bus of the cpu that actually triggers a memory mapped I/O device to respond to that address.
(As if the cpu actually performed a memorymapped I/O operation, but what created that was a PCI device).

Comment: Not as an answer, just my thoughts for now... PCI addresses have three distinct address spaces: config, mem, and I/O. PCI memory space is mapped into the host address space so that data access to devices can be performed by the processor's native load or store instructions. The PCI host bridge should map a PCI memory transaction into a front-side bus transaction to allow TPA (3rd party adapter) or CPU cache hits (and errors) to respond. If neither, then the chipset may remap this back over into a PCI memory space transaction. (These transactions are queued up.) Memory serving.

Comment: @periblepsis Aren't those spaces assigned to a particular bus device. What I mean is since a pci device can be a bus master and has access to memory bus it can as a cpu and hence can perform memory mapped I/O operations just like the cpu

Comment: Did I say anything disagreeing with what you just wrote?

Comment: @periblepsis No I just wanted to know if my question even makes sense

Comment: Not sure what you are wrestling with. But the front side bus can have up to four CPUs. Each CPU has cache (multi-levels.) Also, the front side bus can have a TPA. (The sixth load is the chipset.) Anything on the front side bus can respond to a memory transaction with an error (in the clock just after the transaction) or with a cache-hit (in the clock after the error phase.) It's possible that the memory value being requested by a PCI device, a read transaction let's say, might be satisfied *only* by the cache sitting in one of the CPUs, which hasn't yet written it out to a video card.

Comment: Video memory transactions, in particular, are "lazy." Ordering isn't important in those cases. Yet, that can be a PCI card, yes? All this stuff is handled inside the chipset and it's pretty complex. There is stricter ordering in some cases, less strict in others. There is read-around-writes, and so on. All kinds of rules have to be handled. The PCI master attempting to read from the memory space must allow for specialized responses from cache, for example. It cannot and should not bypass them. Or do you think otherwise? (I'm dragging old memory from decades back. My apologies.)

Comment: @periblepsis Thanks for your previous replies. I just realized a thing and that is a cpu to perform a memory mapped io operation it executes a MOV instruction which moves data from a register to a memory location that's a device,  would the host bridge be required to have a register to do the same operation

Comment: Is there a missing question mark? Or is that just a statement?

Comment: @periblepsis sorry I forget the question mark my bad

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is. The northbridge (or related chipset) is usually where ram is attached and directly connected to the front side bus to monitor and respond to transactions, just like the CPUs and TPA do. For transactions not handled by another CPU or TPA, the chipset is supposed to grab them. Once swallowed by the chipset, the details from there are varied and complex. Some front side bus transactions aren't for RAM and have to be passed along to the PCI or AGP (or whatever.) There are inbound and outbound queues `everywhere`. Queues to RAM, PCI or AGP. What's the Q?

Comment: Even the chipset itself can respond during the cache-hit phase if the chipset deems that it owns the data in an outbound queue that hasn't yet been written out to RAM, for example. If the data is sitting in a chipset queue, and there's a request for that data on the front side bus, then the chipset responds with the data. It has to go find it and present it without disturbing the in-progress queuing process. Meeting all of the various rules, relaxed and strict, and maintaining a consistent perspective is all annoying complicated.

Comment: @periblepsis how does the chipset know where to direct transactions does it have a system memory map ?

Comment: There are and were MSRs and MTRRs. (Probably today, lots more stuff that I'm totally unaware of now.) When the system boots up, code will look around and find stuff and then attempt to configure it. For example, the memory RAM sticks can be of various sizes. So the BIOS configures the memory with an assumption and sees if that leaves gaps. If so, tries another config. Etc. Until the memory sticks are all mapped up and usable as a contiguous area. There's a plug-and-play spec for PCI, I believe. And so on. The BIOS, then O/S are responsible for getting all things mapped up correctly.

Comment: That includes setting up details in the host bridge, the southbridge, any additional PCI bridges, finding all PCI boards and getting them set up, etc. There's a lot to do. But you just start at the beginning and work incrementally forward, slowly building up a picture of the system hardware and making decisions about how to position them. MSRs and MTRRs play a role in all this. Also, don't forget about the I/O space transactions (or configuration space.) I/O is used to directly talk to certain chipset registers and both I/O and configuration space for PCI.

Comment: Mindshare has some good books on all this stuff. I'd recommend getting some of them. Better than listening to me, for sure.